# Getting the error no module named 'mysql' in spyder ide as I'm importing the database from php myadmin

Tags: python, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I want to import the `mysql.connector` from `php myadmin`.
I did install `mysql-connector-python` in command prompt

```
pip3 install mysql-connector-python
```

and it's successfully installed it but still I'm getting the error.
Is there any other way to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using this command to install `mysql connector`

```
pip3 install mysql-connector
```

and check if the import works

```
>>> import mysql.connector
>>>
```